# Need to add "Add to Cart" button Grouped product page in magento 2 for Main Product

Tags: magento2.2, addtocart, grouped-products

I have displayed grouped product in product details page, now I have added "Add to Cart" button for each grouped product button, now problem is if i click on main product "Add to Cart" button then its effect on all group product add to cart button and process for cart, so can you please anyone help how can I customize so i can make working all separate with Main product and group products,

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to this and they depend on how strict your requirements are and/or how much effort you want to put into it:
1) Use a configurable product - this would entail the end user having to choose based on a configurable attribute. Depending on the product, this may be the best way.
2) Use a category page instead of a product page. Default functionality will allow you to add one product to the cart at a time. This is the recommended way if you don't want to extend the functionality. You can make the category page look almost like a product page by using layout updates and/or the native category design functionality.
3) Create a custom product type. Creating custom product types in Magento based on current complex product types (config, group) is not for the faint of heart. Get a developer's help if you want to go this route. There is a pretty good overview of this [by Eric Weise](https://www.classyllama.com/blog/custom-product-types-magento-2)
My general inclination is to work with the core assets before extending. Try #2. If that doesn't do it, go for #3.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul Byrne, But I have created grouped.phtml file and have already displayed "Add to cart" button for all group products but its not working when i applied one solution then group products "add to cart" button working and stop main product "add to cart" button, so can you please give me some idea how can I make working both buttons?